# Create React App executing tests with jest Unexpected identifier

Tags: ecmascript-6, jestjs, create-react-app, babel-jest

i am trying execute test with jest in CRA and i keep getting this weird error.

```
C:\Users\mfonpah\Documents\projects\nexus-web-client\web- 
client\node_modules\auth0-js\src\index.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import 
Authentication from './authentication';                                                                     
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:670:28)
at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] 
(C:\Users\mfonpah\Documents\projects\nexus-web-client\web- 
client\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:152:7)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
```

any ideas on how to fix this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you see this error, your EF6 import statements are not being transpiled. Make sure your babel presets contain "env"

**.babelrc** and **"babel"** property in **package.json**

```
{
    "presets":["env", "react"]
}
```

Depending on your use case you might also need to add the `transform-es2015-modules-amd` plugin, [more here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd/).